# Making up for having accidentally left work early

Tags: professionalism, work-time

My shift schedule just changed and I accidentally left work 30 minutes early. Where I work monitors us very carefully on the computer and they are very strict about these sorts of things. I'm wondering what I should do?

I could make it up by coming in 30 minutes early or leaving 30 minutes late, but if I make it up like this I don't want them to dock pay. The problem is the way the scheduling system works is anything more than the scheduled 8 hours is over time (which pays more) but if I don't record anything than I wont be paid for the time made up.

Any suggestions? Is it fair for me to be paid if I make up the time? I'm worried I'm going to get written up for this. I can talk to my supervisor and tell him I will add appointment reminders to my Outlook to ensure this doesn't happen again.

Comment: We can't tell you how your system works. Just talk to your manager, explain what happened and what you're going to do to stop it happening again.

Comment: Closed. This question comes up here regularly and the answer is always the same: ask your manager how you should handle this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Talk to your manager about it.

This allows you to self-report this mistake and start talking about doing whatever is needed to fix it.

The last thing you want is to give the impression you're covering it up.

Personally, I'd work the missing 30 minutes as agreed with the manager and then work an extra 30 minutes as payback.

Comment: But the first 30 minutes are already the payback.

Comment: @Dominik No, that's just making up the lost time.  I'd work another 30 mins on top of that.

Comment: Yes, mistakes happen, better to fix them then leave them for someone else to find and wonder about your motivations.

Comment: @Kilisi I really hope you meant than*

Comment: @Will yes, good catch, my English isn't great.